# The probability of exactly $r$ guests leaving with their own hats after a random permutation

Tags: probability

#### Problem

Arriving at party $n$ guests throw their hats into pile. When they leave they each take a hat that is chosen randomly from the pile. We want to compute the probability of the event that exactly $r$ guests leave with their own hats. Show that as $n \to \infty$ this probability tends to $\frac{1}{((e)(r!)}$

#### Context

On page 41 of [this book](http://zalsiary.kau.edu.sa/Files/0009120/Files/119387_A_First_Course_in_Probability_8th_Edition.pdf)
is a similar question and I think it helps.

Anyone got any hints on what I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of permutations of $n$ hats with exactly $r$ fixed-points (i.e., exactly $r$ hats return to their original owner) is: $$D_{n,r} = \binom{n}{r}D_{n-r,0} = \frac{n!}{r!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Since, number of ways of selecting $r$ fixed-points is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}$ and forming perfect derangement of the rest is $\displaystyle D_{n-r,0} = D_{n-r,0} = (n-r)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-r}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$

Thus, the required probability is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-r}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$

Take the limit $n \to \infty$ and see that it approaches $\dfrac{e^{-1}}{r!}$